# startActivityForResult from an Activity B and get Result in the Activity A

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Here is the situation:

I have opened an Activity B from an Activity A. I want to finish B and start an Activity C from B with a result in A (StartActivityForResult).

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: Activity A= main Activity
Activity B= page/fragment Manager
Activity C= job to be done in a page from B activity but the result need to be received in A
the only way to pass this problem is to have a page/fragment manager in the main activity but I don't really see how to do it !

Comment: you have to be little more specific

Comment: Use three fragments instead of multiple activities and a Event Bus to communicate between them.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you will be finishing `Activity` B and you have to start `Activity` C

You can start `Activity` C in the `onActivityResult` method of `Activity` A. If you want to pass the data. Pass the data via `intent` to `Activity` C

Answer (score 0):

```
Activity B:
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  //data send to Activity B
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", strtext + "");//your msg
    setResult(2, intent);

}


 Activiy A:
  @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        String sSuName = data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");

        //txtfavouratecount.setText(sSuName);

}
```